# Use pjsip in project

Tags: ios7, pjsip

I am able to compile pjsip iOS for armv7.
After that I am not sure how exactly to use this in a Xcode project.
I mean how to include this Xcode.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

After compiling the PJSIP project for *armv7*, you can open the project in your xcode project. To open the xcode project, go to the path: **/your_pjsip_project_directory/pjsip-apps/src/pjsua/ios/ipjsua.xcodeproj** and open it directly. Generally, **armv7** is used for running your project in your iphone. There are different architecture to run your xcode project.The Following figure show you in detail, to choose which architecture you want to build.

[image]

For adding particular architecture library file into your pjsip project, go to your projects target and select build phases tab. Select **Link Binary with Library** option and click **"+"** button below. Add Your compiled Library file there. Now Build and Run Your Project.

To combine several architecture for supporting multiple architecture to run your project, Follow below link.

check **Supporting multiple architectures (armv6, armv7, armv7s, arm64, and so on)**  section in following link.

Source:https://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Getting-Started/iPhone

Answer (score 1):

Cocoapods was a great option for me when I was struggling to make compiled libraries integrated in my Xcode project it manages dependencies integration.
all you have to do is install it on your machine using this command `$ sudo gem install cocoapods` then go to your Xcode project folder using the terminal `cd ~/project_path` and create a new file `nano Podfile`
use this template and change the project_name with your project name

```
platform :ios, '7.0'
xcodeproj 'project_name'  
pod 'pjsip'
```

then run pod install command you will see another Xcode project will be created
you need then to open the`.xcworkspace` file you will see Pods project will look like this.

[image]

all you have to do now is to start using your pjsip libraries using `#include <pjsua-lib/pjsua.h>`
for reference please visit https://github.com/chebur/pjsip

Answer (score 0):

you have to Link pjsip libraries as well as pjsip headers. 
I could not upload screen shot here as i am new here. So I uploaded the screenshots below links.

First add the headers in Header search path.
For this go to Build Settings and then header search paths.
Then add the header.

See the below url for screenshot:

[add headers like this](http://postimg.org/image/w0k72lwsj/)

After that add libraries in the Linked binary section in general tabs. See the below url for screenshot.

[add library like this](http://postimg.org/image/eojuh63b7/)

Then include the below code in your class.
After that you are ready to use pjsip library.

```
#include <pjsua-lib/pjsua.h>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Images are good but code is better.

Comment: Thank you for your review.Actually adding library and header into xcode is manual process i used.Thats why i answered like this.

Comment: You can always describe it with words in addition to the images.